Загрузка файла и данных JSON в Postman
Необходимо получить данные из фала и перенести в проект, нашел информацию, что это можно сделать через Postman, ранее с ним не работал. Зависимости настроены, пробовал и через файл и через json результат тот же. Что я упускаю?
@RestController

public class PostmanUploadController {


    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .body("file received successfully");
    }

    @PostMapping("/uploadJson")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleJsonInput(@RequestBody Book book) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .body(book.getNameBook());
    }

    @PostMapping("/uploadJsonAndMultipartData")
    public ResponseEntity<String> handleJsonAndMultipartInput(@RequestPart("data") Book book,
                                                              @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .body(book.getId() + book.getNameBook());
    }



Попробуйте у метода handleJsonInput() в аннотации @PostMapping указать параметр consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE.
